# ¿Como puedo manipular objetos con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de manipular una serie de objetos con `javascript` que obtengo como resultado de una consulta `SQL` con `PHP` de la siguiente forma:

```
return array(
      "resultado_banca_privada" => $resultado_banca_privada,
      "resultado_banca_publica" => $resultado_banca_publica,
      "resultado_total_privada" => $resultado_total_privada,
      "resultado_total_publica" => $resultado_total_publica,
      "resultado_total" => $resultado_total
);
```

---

*NOTA:* Quiero aclarar que el array que indique arriba luego lo manipulo con `json_encode` y lo obtengo mediante `Ajax` para así poder manipularlo con `Javascript`.

- Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: "modules/ranking_ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(respuesta)
            {
               console.log(respuesta);
            }
        });
```

---

Al hacer `console.log(respuesta)`, me muestra lo siguiente:

```
{resultado_banca_privada: {…}, resultado_banca_publica: {…}, resultado_total_privada: {…}, resultado_total_publica: {…}, resultado_total: {…}}
```

Al visualizar lo que contiene cada objeto:

```
resultado_banca_privada: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}, 10: {…}, 11: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}, 14: {…}, 15: {…}, 16: {…}, 17: {…}, 18: {…}, 19: {…}, 20: {…}, 21: {…}, 22: {…}, 23: {…}}
resultado_banca_publica: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}}
resultado_total: {PROVISION_1: "81.26", PROVISION_2: "86.85", ABSOLUTA_PROVISION: "-5.59", RELATIVA_PROVISION: "-6.44", MOROSIDAD_1: "2.78", …}
resultado_total_privada: {PROVISION_1: "48.08", PROVISION_2: "53.17", ABSOLUTA_PROVISION: "-5.09", RELATIVA_PROVISION: "-9.57", MOROSIDAD_1: "4.07", …}
resultado_total_publica: {PROVISION_1: "3100.65", PROVISION_2: "3042.45", ABSOLUTA_PROVISION: "58.2", RELATIVA_PROVISION: "1.91", MOROSIDAD_1: ".09", …}
```

Y al visualizar por ejemplo:

- **resultado_banca_privada**

```
resultado_banca_privada:
    0: {BANCO: "SANTANDER", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1732682770.08", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2039855531.58", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-307172761.5", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-15.06", …}
    1: {BANCO: "BBVA", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1420754314.87", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "1722302611.93", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-301548297.06", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-17.51", …}
    2: {BANCO: "BANK OF AMERICA", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1392436385.94", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "1810615055.21", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-418178669.27", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-23.1", …}
    3: {BANCO: "SCOTIABANK", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1080615440.66", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "1381583142.24", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-300967701.58", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-21.78", …}
```

- **resultado_banca_publica:**

```
resultado_banca_publica:
    0: {BANCO: "BARCLAYS BANK", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "22618586764.5", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "25984596036.15", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-3366009271.65", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-12.95", …}
    1: {BANCO: "HAMBURGER SPARKASSE AG", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "2345593960.19", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2709656919.71", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-364062959.52", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-13.44", …}
    2: {BANCO: "VOLKSBANK", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1215693662.5", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "1558430198.95", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-342736536.45", RELATIVA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "-21.99", …}
```

---

Mi duda es a la hora de querer manipular dichos objetos y obtener TODO un campo en específico, por ejemplo `BANCO` o `PROVISION_1` si hablamos de manipular un objeto distinto a `resultado_banca_privada` o `resultado_banca_publica`.

Por ejemplo en `resultado_banca_privada` que trae **N** Bancos el cual me gustaría visualizar TODOS.

¿De que manera se podría realizar? He intentado con `forEach` y `forIn` pero no logro resultados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes es un objeto literal con otros objetos literales dentro, ningún array al parecer. Es decir que todo lo que necesitas saber es sobre objetos en JavaScript.
Una respuesta completa a todo lo que preguntas sería muy larga, lo básico que tienes que saber es:

- Para acceder a las propiedades de un objeto se usa `objeto.la_propiedad` o `objeto["la_propiedad"]`, es preferible el primer método. El segundo método se usa habitualmente cuando el valor de una propiedad está en una variable. En `objeto[la_propiedad]`, `la_propiedad` sería una variable que tiene asignado un string (`var la_propiedad = "BANCO"`).
- Para iterar un objeto directamente se usa `for...in`

Si tu objeto estaría en la variable `obj` un `for..in` sería:

```
for (let propiedad in obj.resultado_banca_privada){
    console.log(obj.resultado_banca_privada[propiedad].BANCO);
}
```

lo que iteramos realmente en este `for in` es el objeto `resultado_banca_privada` y en este caso las propiedades van a ser `0`, `1`, `2` etc.

Muchas veces, resulta útil transformar las propiedades del objeto en array, porque Javascript tiene muchas funciones nativas para iterar y manipular arrays. Lo que se puede usar para ello es `Object.keys()`. Si queremos por ejemplo guardar todos los bancos en un array:

```
const bancos = Object.keys(obj.resultado_banca_privada).map(key => obj.resultado_banca_privada[key].BANCO);
```

Lo que hacemos en el ejemplo precedente es guardar todas las propiedades de `obj.resultado_banca_privada` que van a ser `0`,`1`,`2` etc, ese array (`["0","1","2"...]`) lo iteramos con `.map` donde `key` va ser cada uno de los valores (`0`,`1`,`2` etc), haciendo `obj.resultado_banca_privada[key]` accedemos a cada valor que tambien es un objeto, pero de este objeto necesitamos únicamente una propiedad, entonces accedemos directamente `.BANCO`, no es necesario iterar por las propiedades. Cada iteración de `.map` va a agregar un banco al array `bancos`.

Comment: +1, Tenia varias dudas sobre los objetos en javascript y con esta respuesta quedaron claras, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a los objetos por su jerarquia.

```js
var datos ={
resultado_total: {
      PROVISION_1: "81.26", 
      PROVISION_2: "86.85", 
      ABSOLUTA_PROVISION: "-5.59", 
      RELATIVA_PROVISION: "-6.44", 
      MOROSIDAD_1: "2.78"},
      
resultado_total_privada: {
      PROVISION_1: "48.08", 
      PROVISION_2: "53.17", 
      ABSOLUTA_PROVISION: "-5.09", 
      RELATIVA_PROVISION: "-9.57", 
      MOROSIDAD_1: "4.07"
   },
resultado_total_publica: {
      PROVISION_1: "3100.65", 
      PROVISION_2: "3042.45", 
      ABSOLUTA_PROVISION: "58.2", 
      RELATIVA_PROVISION: "1.91", 
      MOROSIDAD_1: ".09"
      },

}


console.log(datos.resultado_total.PROVISION_1)
```

Tambien puedes obtener todas las llaves de un objeto:

```js
var bancos = {0: 'Banco uno', 1: 'Banco dos'}


var llaves = Object.keys(bancos)

console.log('Las llaves del objeto', llaves)

//Itineramos sobre todos los bancos. 


llaves.forEach( key=>{ console.log(`Llave ${key}: `, bancos[key]) })
```

### Editado

Es un json y puedes acceder a el de esta manera:

```js
var bancos ={ 
    //Estos objetos estan dentro de bancos y accedemos por su llave. 
    //En este primer caso como bancos[0]
    0: {
      //Lo mismo aplica para los siguientes niveles. 
      //Estamos en bancos[0] para mostrar una de estas 
      //dos propiedades la seleccionamos con asi:
      //bancos[0].BANCO
      BANCO: "SANTANDER", 
      TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1732682770.08"
      },
    1: {
      BANCO: "BBVA", 
      TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1732682770.08"
      },
    2: {
      BANCO: "Le banc", 
      TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1732682770.08"
      }
}


//Puedes acceder con notacion de punto. 

console.log(bancos[0].BANCO, bancos[0].TOTAL_ACTIVO_1)

//
```

Comment: He implementado lo que dices de las `llaves` pero aún no logro llegar al resultado que espero, note que en tu ejemplo tienes `var bancos = {0: 'Banco uno', 1: 'Banco dos'}` pero en el mio es `0: {BANCO: "SANTANDER", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "1732682770.08"}` es como que tengo una llave y luego un valor, y en el valor, otra llave y otro valor, no se si estoy en lo correcto ya que no poseo muchos conocimientos sobre este tema

Comment: Edito la pregunta y te explico.